# npm typescript-language-server Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink

Tags: typescript, ubuntu, npm, language-server-protocol

Trying to run the command

```
npm i -g typescript-language-server; npm i -g typescript
```

from here:

https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-typescript/

, but it gives me:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/tsc
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc' -> '/usr/local/bin/tsc'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc' -> '/usr/local/bin/tsc']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc' -> '/usr/local/bin/tsc'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!      path: '../lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc',
npm ERR!      dest: '/usr/local/bin/tsc' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink \'../lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc\' -> \'/usr/local/bin/tsc\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/tsc' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

I don't assume I should run this command as sudo?